# The best way to passing data between widgets in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I develop my own custom widget which is used in some other view. In this custom widget, I have one class property which stores information, let's say that this is a list which gains new items inside the widget. Now I want to get items from this list from the level of my main widget.

How to do that?
I don't want to create a variable like this: `var customWidget = MyCustomWidget()` and then, get the inside variable like `customWidget.createState().myList` - I think this is a terrible solution (and I'm not sure if it will work). Also passing a list to the constructor of my custom widget looks very ugly.

Is there any other way to get other widget's state?

Comment: Also have a look at these sites for architecture examples/ideas
https://medium.com/@maksimrv/reactive-app-state-in-flutter-73f829bcf6a7
https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples

Comment: Hi, Did not understand how you solved it in real, can you help me with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824461/how-to-pass-data-from-child-widget-to-its-parent

Comment: suggestion: instead of posting an update to your question, you can post an answer to your own question, so this question won't appear in the 'unanswered questions'

Comment: Highly recommend Flutter's official documentation on state management: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

This is a list of your possible options and relevant use cases. If you go up one section, they have a great walkthrough on state management in general

Answer (score 43):

First, bear in mind that in Flutter data can only be passed downward. It is by design not possible to access data of children, only parents (although there are some hacks around it).

From this point, there are 2 main solutions to pass data:

1. Add the wanted data to your widgets constructors.

I don't think there is much to say here. Easy to use. But boring when you want to pass one field to all your widget tree. Use this method only when the scope of a value is limited. If it's something like configurations or user details, go for the second solution.

```
class Bar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;

  Bar({this.data});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(data);
  }
}
```

2. Using Flutter's `BuildContext`

Each widget has access to a `BuildContext`. This class allows one widget to fetch information from any of their ancestors using one of the following methods:

- [dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType.html)
- [findAncestorStateOfType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findAncestorStateOfType.html)
- [findAncestorWidgetOfExactType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/findAncestorWidgetOfExactType.html)
- ...

As a matter of fact, if there's data that needs to be accessed many times, prefer `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`.

This uses [`InheritedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html); which are specifics kind of widgets that are extremely fast to access to.

See [Flutter: How to correctly use an Inherited Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491860/flutter-how-to-correctly-use-an-inherited-widget/49492495#49492495) for more details on their usage

---

As a side note, there a third solution. Which is [`GlobalKey`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html)

I won't go into too many details, as this is more a hack than a proper solution. (see [Builder versus GlobalKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329065/builder-versus-globalkey/51527915#51527915))

But basically, it allows getting the state/context of *any* widgets outside of the `build` call. Be it parents **or children**.

Comment: The first sentence is what I was looking for, for a few hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

on my side I implemented onChanged  callback.

For example In my Widget :

```
class ObjectiveCardWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Objective? objective;
  final ValueChanged<Objective?>? onChanged;
  ObjectiveCardWidget({this.objective, this.onChanged});
  @override
  State<ObjectiveCardWidget> createState() => _ObjectiveCardWidgetState();
}
```

when my data is updated un my custom widget I just called :

```
widget.onChanged!(newValue);  // newvalue has been set previously
```

In my parentWidget I used onChanged as usual:

```
ObjectiveCardWidget(
              objective: myObjective,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  myObjective = value;
                });
              })
```

Hope it will help.