# Flutter Inherited Widget - Missing some listener

Tags: flutter, state, inherited-widget

I'm trying to get the following to work. Changes to the app model state are not picked up via the InheritedWidget 'AppStateProvider'. I've manage to get this working with sinks/streams but was hoping to established a simpler structure.

This is just a test application to switch between various app modes.

What's missing?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AppStateProvider(
    child: RootPage(),
    appState: new AppState(),
  ));
}

enum AppMode { introduction, login, home }

class AppState {
  AppMode appMode;
  AppState({
    this.appMode = AppMode.introduction,
  });
}

class AppStateProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final AppState appState;

  AppStateProvider({Key key, Widget child, this.appState})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;

  static AppStateProvider of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(AppStateProvider)
        as AppStateProvider);
  }
}

class RootPage extends StatelessWidget {
  AppMode _mode;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Inherited Widget Test',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      home: _body(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _body(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = AppStateProvider.of(context); //Registers as a listener
    final state = provider.appState;
    _mode = state.appMode;

    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Offstage(
          offstage: _mode != AppMode.introduction,
          child: new MaterialApp(
            home: ColorsListPage(
              color: Colors.red,
              targetAppMode: AppMode.login,
              title: "Intro",
            ),
          ),
        ),
        new Offstage(
          offstage: _mode != AppMode.login,
          child: new MaterialApp(
            home: ColorsListPage(
              color: Colors.blue,
              targetAppMode: AppMode.home,
              title: "Login",
            ),
          ),
        ),
        new Offstage(
          offstage: _mode != AppMode.home,
          child: new MaterialApp(
            home: ColorsListPage(
              color: Colors.green,
              targetAppMode: AppMode.introduction,
              title: "Home",
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ColorDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final MaterialColor color;
  final int materialIndex;
  final AppMode targetAppMode;

  ColorDetailPage(
      {this.color, this.title, this.targetAppMode, this.materialIndex: 500});

  @override
  _ColorDetailPageState createState() => new _ColorDetailPageState();
}

class _ColorDetailPageState extends State<ColorDetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = AppStateProvider.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: widget.color,
        title: Text(
          '$widget.title[$widget.materialIndex]',
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: widget.color[widget.materialIndex],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            provider.appState.appMode = widget.targetAppMode;
          });
        },
        heroTag: null,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorsListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final MaterialColor color;
  final String title;
  final ValueChanged<int> onPush;
  final AppMode targetAppMode;
  final List<int> materialIndices = [
    100,
    200,
    300,
    400,
    500,
    600,
    700,
    800,
    900,
  ];

  ColorsListPage({this.color, this.targetAppMode, this.title, this.onPush});

  @override
  _ColorsListPageState createState() => new _ColorsListPageState();
}

class _ColorsListPageState extends State<ColorsListPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final provider = AppStateProvider.of(context);

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          backgroundColor: widget.color,
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: _buildList(context),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              provider.appState.appMode = widget.targetAppMode;
            });
          },
          heroTag: null,
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.materialIndices.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext content, int index) {
        int materialIndex = widget.materialIndices[index];
        return Container(
            color: widget.color[materialIndex],
            child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  "$materialIndex",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                ),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ColorDetailPage(
                              color: widget.color,
                              title: widget.title,
                              targetAppMode: widget.targetAppMode,
                              materialIndex: materialIndex,
                            )),
                  );
                }
                //onTap: () => onPush(materialIndex),
                ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your `InheritedWidget` inside a `StatefulWidget`

```
class _AppStateProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final AppStateProviderState data;

  _AppStateProvider({Key key, @required Widget child, @required this.data})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => true;
}

class AppStateProvider extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final AppState appState;

  AppStateProvider({
    @required this.child,
    @required this.appState,
  });

  static AppStateProviderState of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_AppStateProvider)
            as _AppStateProvider)
        .data;
  }

  @override
  AppStateProviderState createState() => AppStateProviderState(
        appState,
      );
}

class AppStateProviderState extends State<AppStateProvider> {
  AppState appState;

  AppStateProviderState(this.appState);

  void updateAppMode(AppMode appMode) {
    setState(() {
      appState.appMode = appMode;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _AppStateProvider(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

### [for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492495/10059717)

pay attention to this method:

```
  void updateAppMode(AppMode appMode) {
    setState(() {
      appState.appMode = appMode;
    });
  }
```

you can use it like this:

```
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      provider.updateAppMode(widget.targetAppMode);
    },
    heroTag: null,
  ),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did get something similar working. Wrapping in a stateful widget is not always required to use an inherited widget. So I curious to know why it’s tequired here. I was hoping for a simpler solution. That’s a lot of boiler plate code relative to the Streams and sinks option.

Comment: @CraigJarman You need to replace the `InheritedWidget` object to rebuild the widget tree. So, you have to use the `State` with the `setState` method. Alternatively, you can use a `ScopedModel`: https://proandroiddev.com/you-might-not-need-redux-the-flutter-edition-9c11eba006d7