# Flutter- Is it safe to use static variable for userId

Tags: flutter

I want to know whether it's ok to do or I should not do.
For example I created class like this:

```
class Utils {
    static String uid;
}
```

And get the user's `uniqueId` when user logged in and set it like so:

```
Utils.uid = uniqueId;
```

After that, just pass around.
Let's say I have there tabs and starts with first tab which get `uid` here and when go to second tab, use `uid` for something.
Is it something I should not do or is it ok?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: flutter 3.19 is out now so are there any best way to do this? rather then inherited widget or user provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In general inside Flutter, *everything* should be coming from a widget. Be it configurations, API data, authentification, or whatever you can think of.

While you could make it work with singletons/static properties, you loose a lot. By wrapping everything inside a widget; it ensures that whenever the data change, everything gets reloaded correctly.

In this situation you'll want to expose user informations using an `InheritedWidget`.

[More informations here on how to use them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491860/flutter-how-to-correctly-use-an-inherited-widget/49492495#49492495)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I don't think I understand correctly. So let inheritedWidget hold uid and being inherited by basically every other widget(because uid is used almost everywhere). And every time I need uid, then get from inherited widget. Like a widget version of singleton.  Am I understand right?

Comment: That's the idea. The difference being that whenever a value of `InheritedWidget` change, all widgets who depends from that inherited are automatically updated.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RémiRousselet now we are flutter 3.19 so now that is the best way to do this? same inherited widget or user provider or something else? also it would be great if method is as simple as it can be for new flutter developer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really say wether it's right or wrong cause it depends, but what I am doing and I've seen several others do is to store the user related info like user id in **SharedPreferences** once the user logs into the application.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the comment I'll check that for sure!

Answer (score 1):

now you can use Providers to share data across the pages and widgets
Providers reload only necessary widgets which keep top performance than static properties