# Flutter: Singleton data, getter called on null

Tags: http, null, singleton, flutter

after I've retrieved data (an user) from an http request, I want to put this data into a singleton. Then, in another view, I want to show the name of this user in the sidebar, but it says "The getter 'user' was called on null."
Here's my code:

```
var user = await getUser(_username, _password);

      if (user.loginError == false){
        model.user = user;

        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            '/home_view', ModalRoute.withName('/home_view'));
       }
```

And here's when I try to use the user.name:

```
Widget hamburgerMenu() {
  Model model;
  return new Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          accountName: Text(model.user.name,
            ...
```

Comment: You shouldn't use singletons in flutter. Instead use inheritedWidgets. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491860/flutter-how-to-correctly-use-an-inherited-widget/49492495#49492495

Comment: Why are singletons so bad in flutter?

Comment: When their value changes, widgets that depends on it are not automatically reloaded. Inheritedwidgets are there to solve this situation. They are basically singletons that reload widgets that depends on it

Comment: oh, I see. Thanks then, I will try to understand them!

Comment: But if I never want to change these item, I think I could also use a singleton, don't I?

Comment: Not saying you can't, but it's a bad practice. What if you want to handle disconnection or renaming the user for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `hamburgerMenu()` you are declaring the `Model model;` but you never asign any value to it. It will always be null. If it's a singleton you need to do something like this

```
Widget hamburgerMenu() {
  Model model = Model.instance;//You fetch the instance of the singleton
  return new Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          accountName: Text(model.user.name,
            ...
```

Also, don't do this inside the build function. If it's a stateful widget do it in the `initState()` function

Comment: oooh yes, Didn't notice my mistake. Thanks a lot!