# Does Flutter have Data Binding?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start) in Flutter?

I have checked [the official documentation](https://flutter.io/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes/) about the field changes but I couldn't find anyting.

Comment: Can you please provide a use case or code example to better elaborate your question.

Comment: There is no need for that in Flutter.

Comment: I was flowing Flutter Course of Udacity and this the quiz where I seek the data binding: https://github.com/flutter/udacity-course/tree/master/course/06_input/task_06_input 
 I just want to bind Input value to Output Text with proper formula.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

Instead Flutter has a widget binding, namely InheritedWidget.
It binds two or more widgets together (one provider and some consumers) so that whenever one updates, all of its dependencies are forced to update too.

See [Flutter: How to correctly use an Inherited Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491860/flutter-how-to-correctly-use-an-inherited-widget/49492495?s=5|62.0789#49492495) for more details on how to use InheritedWidgets.