# How to access context from widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working on a flutter application and I have an Inherited Widget class.
There is a function in my InheritedWidget Class which needs to access BuildContext.
Is it possible to access context(BuildContext) from widget object?
If yes, what are the ways to access it.

```
class ApiClient extends InheritedWidget{

  final String baseUrl;

  ApiClient({
    @required this.baseUrl,
    @required Widget child
  }):super(child:child);

  static ApiClient of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(ApiClient);
  }

  Future<http.Response> login(String email, String password){

    Map<String, String> body = {
       "username":email,
       "password":password,
       "client_secret": //This I want to read from an EnvironmentConfig
 //file which is also an InheritedWidget And In order to read that I need context,
    };
    return _network.post(baseUrl+ApiEndpoints.LOGIN, body:json.encode(body), headers: ApiHeaders.headers);
  }



  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;


}
```

Comment: Can you share your widget? You're likely to be doing something wrong

Comment: @RémiRousselet I have added related code snippet.

Comment: As I expected. You should not have any logic inside your InheritedWidget. It should be used *only* to hold variables. You will need to combine it to a StatefulWidget; See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491860/flutter-how-to-correctly-use-an-inherited-widget/49492495?s=5|63.2436#49492495

Comment: @RémiRousselet However I want to have some functions in my InheritedWidget. Is it a bad practise to put them in InheritedWidgets?

Comment: There is not point in having them here. You can make your static `of` method return the State instead, and add your methods there.