# Flutter - InheritedModel still update child even if it does not match an aspect

Tags: flutter, inherited-widget

Good day. I've watched a video about Flutter's InheritedModel and got interested on it. Unfortunately, I can't seems to make it work properly.

---

Summary: Need help how to properly implement InheritedModel.

**Expected Code Output:** Widget `CountText` should not be updated when updating `count` parameter in `CountModel`.

**Actual Code Output**: `CountText` still updates (I think this is due to that the parent widget is a `StatefulWidget`)

---

## **Details**

I am trying to implement a `Counter` app using `InheritedModel`. Code below is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CountModel extends InheritedModel<String> {

  final int count;  

  CountModel({ this.count, child }) : super(child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(CountModel oldWidget) {
    if (oldWidget.count != count) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotifyDependent(InheritedModel<String> oldWidget, Set<String> dependencies) {
    if (dependencies.contains('counter')) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  static CountModel of(BuildContext context, String aspect) {
    return InheritedModel.inheritFrom<CountModel>(context, aspect: aspect);
  }

}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Counter',
      theme: Theme.of(context),
      home: Counter(),
    );
  }
}

class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CounterState createState() => CounterState();
}

class CounterState extends State<Counter> {

  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // title: Text("Counter"),
      ),
      body: CountModel(
        count: count,
        child: CounterText()
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            ++count;          
          });
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterText extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CountModel model = CountModel.of(context, 'test');
    return Text('Count: ${model.count}');
  }  

}
```

---

I have a CountModel as `InheritedModel` and a `CountText` widget which consumes the data from the `CountModel`. As you can see in the implementation of the `CountText`, it pass `test` when getting the `CountModel`. In my understanding, it should not be updated when the `count` value is updated in the CountModel. Unfortunately, this does not happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you should use **const**.

Add const to *CounterText* constructor

```
class CounterText extends StatelessWidget {
  const CounterText();
  ...
}
```

and use *const* when you create instance of *CounterText()* (*const CounterText()*)

```
class CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
      body: CountModel(..., child: const CounterText()),
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

And voila

I have described **why this is happening [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53733473/1620380)** in details

Comment: Hi @maksimr Thank you~! I was able to make it work by following your guide. :D