# InheritedWidget not accessible in new route

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter and confused about how `InheritedWidget` works with routes. I'm using an SQLite database with the sqflite library. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is, when my app is launched, I want all widgets that don't require the database to show right away. For instance, the bottomNavigationBar of my `Scaffold` doesn't need the database but the body does. So I want the bottomNavigationBar to show right away, and a `CircularProgressIndicator` to be shown in the body. Once the database is open, I want the body to show content loaded from the database.

So, in my attempt to achieve this, I use `FutureBuilder` before my `Scaffold` to open the database. While the `Future` is not completed, I pass `null` for the drawer and a `CircularProgressBar` for the body, and the bottomNavigationBar as normal. When the `Future` completes, I wrap the drawer and body (called `HomePage`) both with their own `InheritedWidget` (called `DataAccessor`). This seems to work, as I can access the `DataAccessor` in my `HomePage` widget. But, when I use the `Navigator` in my drawer to navigate to my `SettingsScreen`, my `DataAccessor` is not accessible and returns null.

Here's some example code, not using a database but just a 5 second delayed `Future`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          Widget drawer;
          Widget body;
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            drawer = DataAccessor(
              child: Drawer(
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Text("Settings"),
                      onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsScreen()))
                    )
                  ]
                )
              )
            );
            body = DataAccessor(child: HomePage());  
          }
          else {
            drawer = null;
            body = Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return Scaffold(
            drawer: drawer,
            body: body,
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Container(), title: Text("One")),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Container(), title: Text("Two"))
              ]
            )
          );
        }
      )
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        DataAccessor dataAccessor = DataAccessor.of(context); //dataAccessor IS NOT null here
        print("HomePage: ${dataAccessor == null}");
        return Text("HomePage");
    }
}

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        DataAccessor dataAccessor = DataAccessor.of(context); //dataAccessor IS null here
        print("SettingsScreen: ${dataAccessor == null}");
        return Text("SettingsScreen");
    }
}

class DataAccessor extends InheritedWidget {

    DataAccessor({Key key, Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

    @override
    bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;

    static DataAccessor of(BuildContext context) => context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(DataAccessor);

}
```

It's possible I'm doing things wrong. Not sure how good of practice storing widgets in variables is. Or using the same `InheritedWidget` twice? I've also tried wrapping the entire `Scaffold` with my `DataAccessor` (and having the database as null while it is loading), but the issue still remains where I can't get my `DataAccessor` in my `SettingsScreen`.

I've read that a possible solution is to put my `InheritedWidget` before the `MaterialApp` but I don't want to resort to this. I don't want a whole new screen to show while my database is opening, I want my widgets that don't need the database to be shown. This should be possible somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: There is an open issue that would make that easier (pls ) https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/80303

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in the last paragraph is what you need. The `MaterialApp` contains the `Navigator` which manages the routes, so for all of your routes to have access to the same `InheritedWidget` that has to be above the `Navigator`, i.e. above the `MaterialApp`.

Use [Remi's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491860/flutter-how-to-correctly-use-an-inherited-widget/49492495#49492495) and you end up with a widget tree like this:

- `MyApp` (has the static `.of()` returning `MyAppState`)
- `MyAppState`, whose `build` returns `_MyInherited(child: MaterialApp(...))` and whose `initState` starts loading the database, calling `setState` when loaded.

When building your home page you have access to `MyAppState` via `.of`, so can ascertain whether the database has loaded or not. If it has not, just build the database independent widgets; if it has, build all the widgets.