# My Text widget ui does not update even after using setstate

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display price based on the selected item from my picker , but my Text ui is not changing after onSelectedItemChanged Picker function is triggered even after using setState. The changes only reflect after i use the flutter hot reload.

//The price varaible is the variable that changes

```
 int price = 0;

              
// This is the widget displaying the price variable based on selected item
Text(price,
  style: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.white,
  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
 fontSize: 15.0));
```

//This is the picker widget

```
 Widget buildPicker() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 350,
      child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
        return CupertinoPicker(
          scrollController: scrollController,
          itemExtent: 64,
          selectionOverlay: CupertinoPickerDefaultSelectionOverlay(
            background: CupertinoColors.activeBlue.withOpacity(0.2),
          ),
          children: List.generate(productController.data.length, (index) {
            final isSelected = this.index == index;
            final item = productController.data[index];
            final color =
                isSelected ? CupertinoColors.activeBlue : CupertinoColors.black;
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                item.size!,
                style: TextStyle(color: color, fontSize: 32),
              ),
            );
          }),
          onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
            setState(() {
              this.index = index;
            final item = productController.data[index];
            price= item.price!;
            print(price);
         });
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

// The text widget displaying the price does not change unless i use the flutter hot reload before the changes reflect. Please what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: StatefulBuilder rebuild your buildPicker, it didn't able to build whole context that's why value won't change. When you used hot reload then change the value

Comment: Ooh, thank you for the explanation. So how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check  this line

`StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState)` here `setState` is referring to `StatefulBuilder`'s state not class level state, that's why your page screen is not updating, I will suggest renaming this something so that it won't make us confuse and able to use class level `setState`.

This snippet will provide you the idea , check I'm renaming to use state level `setState` method.

```dart
            builder: (context) => StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setStateSB) {
                //<- this will update ui inside dilaog
                        onSelectedItemChanged: (v) {
                          print(v);
                          setStateSB(() {
                            // for inner changes
                            price = v;
                          });

                          setState(() {
                            // using class level state
                            price = v;
                          });
                        },
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked, though i have  switched to using GetX state management.

Answer (score 0):

StatefulBuilder rebuild your buildPicker, it didn't able to build whole context that's why value won't change. When you used hot reload then change the value.

You can solve this problem by using state management like Bloc, getx, provider and otherwise you can use inherited widget.

For more about -

**State management** https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

**Inherited widget** [Flutter: How to correctly use an Inherited Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491860/flutter-how-to-correctly-use-an-inherited-widget)

Comment: Thank you for your help, i used GetX state management for it!

Comment: that's great to use GetX. Happy coding