# Flutter setState to another class?

Tags: dart, flutter, setstate

I have a root class `RootPage` which is a `StatefulWidget` which is always in view. I would like to change the `body` in `RootPage` which is controlled by `RootPage's currentPage Widget` from different classes such as my `FeedPage` class and any other class that I make?

Example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RootPageState createState() => new _RootPageState();
}
class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  FeedPage feedPage;

  Widget currentPage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    feedPage = FeedPage();

    currentPage = feedPage;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      //Current page to be changed from other classes too?
      body: currentPage
    );
  }
}



class FeedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _feedPageState createState() => new _feedPageState();
}
class _feedPageState extends State<FeedPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          //change the currentPage in RootPage so it switches FeedPage away and gets a new class that I'll make
        });
      },
      child: new Text('Go to a new page but keep root, just replace this feed part'),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm sure there's an obvious answer but I can't seem to figure out how to do it efficiently so it'll be easy to integrate future classes and keep my Root always in view.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use **callbacks functions** to achieve this. Please refer to the below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RootPageState createState() => new _RootPageState();
}
class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  FeedPage feedPage;

  Widget currentPage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    feedPage = FeedPage(this.callback);

    currentPage = feedPage;
  }

  void callback(Widget nextPage) {
    setState(() {
      this.currentPage = nextPage;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      //Current page to be changed from other classes too?
        body: currentPage
    );
  }
}



class FeedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Function callback;

  FeedPage(this.callback);

  @override
  _feedPageState createState() => new _feedPageState();
}
class _feedPageState extends State<FeedPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        this.widget.callback(new NextPage());
//        setState(() {
//          //change the currentPage in RootPage so it switches FeedPage away and gets a new class that I'll make
//        });
      },
      child: new Text('Go to a new page but keep root, just replace this feed part'),
    );
  }
}
```

This is very similar to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463906/emit-the-data-to-parent-widget-in-flutter/51468131#51468131) and you could refer 3rd point in my answer.

Comment: the callback you did in 'this.widget.callback(new NextPage());'  is instead the 'setState(){}' or you need them both?

Comment: Are you asking the commented `setState` just below the `this.widget.callback(new NextPage());` ?

Comment: Instead of setState. We dont need setState there.

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian, I'm trying to do the same thing, but I'm getting "The instance member 'callback' can't be accessed in an initializer. "

So basically, I have to make the callback static, to be able to pass it as arg to other screen, which means I can't use setState inside of it.

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Apparently, the constructor must be called within initState() to work.

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian Thanks for this beautiful code and it's working very well for my end, but I have one question for my side, how can get the previous screen when we click Onbackpress?

Comment: I think there could be a possible memory leak here -- if you set `currentPage`, then `feedPage` is no longer returned from `_RootPageState.build()`, which means that when `_RootPageState.dispose()` is called, `feedPage.dispose()` will not be called.

Answer (score 46):

**Screenshot (Null safe):**

[image]

---

**Full code:**

This is the `ParentPage`:

```dart
class ParentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentPageState createState() => _ParentPageState();
}

class _ParentPageState extends State<ParentPage> {
  int _count = 0;

  // Pass this method to the child page.
  void _update(int count) {
    setState(() => _count = count);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Value (in parent) = $_count'),
          ChildPage(update: _update),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the `ChildPage`:

```dart
class ChildPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<int> update;
  ChildPage({required this.update});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => update(100), // Passing value to the parent widget.
      child: Text('Update (in child)'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I know that you need a solution for your specific code but I recommed to you to have a look on BloC pattern as it the recommended aproch when you want to pass state changes from widget to another especially multiple pages

the idea is simple although the implementation is a "little bit" more complicated

Comment: *don't give me a fish but teach me how to fish*. **Elegant answer!**

Answer (score 2):

Actually the most effective way to do this is using BLoC package in flutter and implement it from the top of the widget tree so all inheriting widgets can use the same bloc.
If you have worked with Android before - it works like Android Architecture Components - you separate data and state management from the UI - so you do not setState in the UI, but instead use the BLoC to manage state.
So you can set and access the same data - from any widget that inherits from the top widget where the BLoC is implemented, for more complex apps, it is very useful.

This is where you can find the package:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc#-readme-tab-

Write-up:
https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/08/reactive-programming-streams-bloc/

And a great tutorial on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTExlt1nJZI&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4jCBkrirvVGr5b8rC95VAQ5&index=7

Comment: just wanted to add getx

Answer (score 0):

This was a tricky question but I got a solution for this question I to faced this problem so many times. So let's first solve your problem. And this is the solution for your code

Lets first save this file with a name feedPage.dart

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class FeedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _feedPageState createState() => new _feedPageState();
}
class _feedPageState extends State<FeedPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          //change the currentPage in RootPage so it switches FeedPage away and gets a new class that I'll make
        });
      },
      child: new Text('Go to a new page but keep root, just replace this feed part'),
    );
  }
}`
```

And then import that file into your main file

```
`
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'feedPage.dart'
class RootPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RootPageState createState() => new _RootPageState();
}
class _RootPageState extends State<RootPage> {
  FeedPage feedPage;

  Widget currentPage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    feedPage = FeedPage();

    currentPage = feedPage;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      //Current page to be changed from other classes too?
      body: currentPage
    );
  }
}`
```

In flutter you cant write multiple Stateful widgets in one dart file you have to create that as a widget and use it in your code as setState is an attribute of a Stateful widget we have write this code in an diffrent file

Problem Solved......:)