# Flutter how to pass back data from model

Tags: flutter

I'm practicing draggable widget. Thanks to amazing video by Tensor Programming. I was able to understand how things work. 
However, there is one thing I'm not sure. Let's say if one of the `DragBox` tapped, I want to get text inside of the tapped `DragBox`. I wrapped `Container` with `GestureDetector`, but I have no idea how to make `onTap` function pass `widget.label` to `AppState`.

Should I use constructor or something to pass it?
Does anyone know hot to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: App(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AppState createState() => AppState();
}

class AppState extends State<App> {
  Color caughtColor = Colors.grey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        DragBox(Offset(0.0, 0.0), 'Box One', Colors.blueAccent),
        DragBox(Offset(200.0, 0.0), 'Box Two', Colors.orange),
        DragBox(Offset(300.0, 0.0), 'Box Three', Colors.lightGreen),
        Positioned(
          left: 100.0,
          bottom: 0.0,
          child: DragTarget(
            onAccept: (Color color) {
              caughtColor = color;
            },
            builder: (
              BuildContext context,
              List<dynamic> accepted,
              List<dynamic> rejected,
            ) {
              return Container(
                width: 200.0,
                height: 200.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: accepted.isEmpty ? caughtColor : Colors.grey.shade200,
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("Drag Here!"),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DragBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final Offset initPos;
  final String label;
  final Color itemColor;

  DragBox(this.initPos, this.label, this.itemColor);

  @override
  DragBoxState createState() => DragBoxState();
}

class DragBoxState extends State<DragBox> {
  Offset position = Offset(0.0, 0.0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    position = widget.initPos;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
        left: position.dx,
        top: position.dy,
        child: Draggable(
          data: widget.itemColor,
          child: GestureDetector(
           onTap() {
            // want to pass widget.label here
           },
          child: Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
            color: widget.itemColor,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                widget.label,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
             ),
            ),
          ),
         ),
          onDraggableCanceled: (velocity, offset) {
            setState(() {
              position = offset;
            });
          },
          feedback: Container(
            width: 120.0,
            height: 120.0,
            color: widget.itemColor.withOpacity(0.5),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                widget.label,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798498/flutter-setstate-to-another-class/51798698#51798698) answer. In the link

- `RootPage` is similar to `App`,
- `AppState` is similar to `_RootPageState`,
- `DragBox` is similar to `FeedPage` and
- `DragBoxState` is similar to `_feedPageState`

If it is not helpful, please comment, i can put example for your `App`

Comment: Thank you so much you made my day!

Comment: Sorry it says  `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.`

Comment: That's okay. Thanks

Comment: @TwoSan, that's funny because you have 419 reputation-score. Would it be a bug?