# Set State of parent Widget

Tags: flutter, parent

Let's say, I have a custom button widget and I want to set the state of it's parent using `setState`. How exactly can I access the parent widget's state from my custom button? Is it even possibile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **callbacks functions** to achieve this. You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798498/flutter-setstate-to-another-class/51798698#51798698).

In the link

- FeedPage is similar to CustomButton(ChildWiget)
- RootPage is similar to ParentWiget

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define global key
static GlobalKey gk= GlobalKey();

// Assign global key in constructor
class mainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  mainScreen(): super(key: data.gk);

  // Call the setState from parent widget or from any where
  if (gk.currentState != null) {
    data.gk.currentState!.setState(() {

    })
  }
}
```