# Flutter: Refresh another Widget State from Another Route

Tags: dart, flutter

At the HompePage, am navigating to Settings page with;

```
 Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Settings()));
```

the `Settings()` page contains an `int` input to allow user specify the number of posts they want to see at the `HomePage`. When users input the number and form.save, the value is stored in `SharedPreferences`. But when the user go back to the `HomePage`, the initial number of post still there. I want the `HomePage`state to refresh so that the number of post the user specify at the Settings Page will take effect immediately the form is saved.

Below is some snippets of my code;

This is the form `_submit` on `Settings()` page,

```
_submit() async {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (form.validate()) {
      prefs.setInt('defaultField', newva);
      form.save();
      final mysb = SnackBar(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        content: new Text(
          'Data Saved Successfully',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      );
      _scaffoldKey.currentState?.showSnackBar(mysb);
      myHomePageState.setState(() {
        newSULength = newva;
      });
      print('Done for $newva');
    }
  }
```

This is my `MyHomePage()`

```
MyHomePageState myHomePageState = new MyHomePageState();

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => new MyHomePageState();
  static MyHomePageState of(BuildContext context){
    final MyHomePageState navigator = context.ancestorStateOfType(const TypeMatcher<MyHomePageState>());
    assert(() {
      if(navigator == null) {
        throw new FlutterError('Error occoured');
      }
      return true;
    }());

    return navigator;
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int newSULength = 0;

void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loadDF();
  }

  set newle(String value) => setState(() => _string = value);


  loadDF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      newSULength = (prefs.getInt('defaultField') ?? 5);
      for (int i = 0; i < newSULength; i++) {

\\todos
      }
    });
    print('Done');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `callbacks` to indicate the `HomePage` that the `Settings` page changed some value in shared preference. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51798698/5305962)