# Flutter, send parameter previous screen

Tags: dart, flutter

I have two screens A and B. I clicked a button from A and open B screen. When opened B screen I choose something and go back to A screen with:

```
      Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => A(data: data)));
```

but it doesn't work.

How can go back to the previous screen with data using pop or similar things?

Comment: This could be one option...https://stackoverflow.com/a/51798698/5305962

Answer (score 3):

the `pop` method takes an optional parameter that you can return to the previous screen. You would use it like so:

```
// In screen A:
final result = await Navigator.push(...); // Here you just push the route like normal

// In screen B:
Navigator.pop(context, data); // Where data is whatever you want to return to screen A
```

In the above example, `result` will contain whatever you returned from screen B

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Your answer helped me a lot!