# Flutter - Call a method on some children from parent

Tags: flutter

I'm discovering Flutter and I really love it.
I'm building a simple app where I have few instances of Statefull custom widget "Counter" on a Scafold's body, and I have a "Reset" button on the drawer.

What's the best way to call a "resetCounter" method on all "Counter" instances when tap on the "Reset" button ?

I've managed the other way (calling a callback method of a parent from a child), but I can't find the other way. The only solution I've found is by using GlobalKeys, but it doesn't seems appropriate.

Thanks

Comment: Please add some code of what you've already tried

Comment: I think **callback** is better for your usecase. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798498/flutter-setstate-to-another-class/51798698#51798698

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed for your case callback function might be the right one. But when your app will grow the widget hierarchy will become more and more complex. For now you have `Parent —> Child` relationship and it’s quite easy to pass callback function, but when you’ll get `Parent —> Widget A—> Widget B—> Child` situation in order to pass callback from Parent to Child you’ll need to pass it through `Widget A` and `Widget B` as well.

For me, your problem sounds like a perfect candidate for **reactive streams**. You may create a `Sink` which will be used when user tap on `Reset` button and your `Counter` will observe this event and handle it with `resetCounter` method. You may learn more about reactive programming (and other ways to solve your problem) from [this presentation](https://youtu.be/RS36gBEp8OI).

Comment: Thanks @olexas, I think that's what I'm looking for, I'll look into it and come back here. Thanks !

Comment: You definitely put me in the right direction, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach to extend ChangeNotifier, and add child as listeners. Once parent perform an action, you can call notifyChange to trigger child widgets callbacks.