# How to pass parameters to callbacks in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class ExtractArgumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/extractArguments';

  double price = 0;

  _changeprice(num){
      setState(){
        price+ = num;
      }
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final MealArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MyApp'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20,),

          ViewCard(args.combo,_changeprice()),
        ]));
```

This is the parent class. I passed the function `_changePrice()` to `ViewCard` so that I can change the value of the price later.
This is giving me an

> error "1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found"

but I can't pass an argument to `_changePrice` as that defeats the whole purpose of using this callback.
What I'm trying to implement is similar to what was suggested in [Emit the data to parent Widget in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463906/emit-the-data-to-parent-widget-in-flutter).

The child class ViewCard passed this callback to another child called `OneItem`.

```
class OneItem extends StatefulWidget {
  OneItem(this.combo, this.index, this.changePrice);
  final Combo combo;
  final int index;
  final VoidCallback changePrice;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => OneItemState();
}

class OneItemState extends State<OneItem> {
  List<bool> Vals = new List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    int count = widget.combo.items.length;

    Vals = List<bool>.generate(count, (_) => false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          child: Text(widget.combo.items[widget.index].item),
          alignment: Alignment(-1, 0),
        ),
        Align(
            child: Text(widget.combo.items[widget.index].price),
            alignment: Alignment(0.1, 0)),
        Align(
            child: Checkbox(
              value: Vals[widget.index],
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  Vals[widget.index] = value;
                  if(value == true){double childPrice = double.parse(widget.combo.items[widget.index].price); }
                  else{double val = double.parse(widget.combo.items[widget.index].price); 
                        double childPrice = -1*val;}
                  widget.changePrice(childPrice);                        
                  //widget.changePrice();
                });
              },
            ),
            alignment: Alignment(0.6, 0)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You call `widget.changePrice(childPrice);` from `OneItemState`, so `changePrice` can't be `VoidCallback`

```
typedef IntCallback = Function(int num);

/* ... */

class OneItem extends StatefulWidget {
  OneItem(this.combo, this.index, this.changePrice);
  final Combo combo;
  final int index;
  final IntCallback changePrice;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => OneItemState();
}

/* ... */

ViewCard(args.combo, _changeprice) // function name without braces
```

I would do it like this

Answer (score 20):

You could declare a `Function` callback, like this:

```
final void Function(double price) changePrice;
```

Here another example to understand it better:

```
final bool Function(String id, double price) updateItem;

bool isPriceUpdated = widget.updateItem("item1", 7.5);
```