# Access data between screens in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Im having two screens.

lets say Screen1 and Screen2.

Screen 1 is within a TabView and have couple of checkboxes which I need to validate if either is chosen before proceeding to get them from there and pass to an API call from a button which is in Screen2. Screen2 is the parent(holder) of the TabViews.

Basically ,

- Screen1 have check boxes.
- Screen2 have a submit button.
- Submit button
  should be activate only if at least one checkbox is selected.
- If that
  condition is passed, and submit button is pressed, then selected
  check box values should be passed to the api call.

I can manage the API calling part. but wanna have an idea or an example of managing the above between Screen1 and Screen2.
Can someone provide and insight or an example?

**Update**

with a helpful comment from a fellow flutter enthusiast, I've update the code.
The widget flow is as follows.

```
//ParentWidget ==> has the list if TabViews and also a button to submit, 

TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: _tabViewList,
)

//and the button 
Consumer<UpdateItemProvider>(
        builder: (_, UpdateItemProvider updateItemProvider, __) {
          return ButtonWidget(
            btnColor: CustomColors.green600,
            borderColor: CustomColors.green600,
            textColor: CustomColors.mWhite,
            text: "Continue",
            eButtonType: eButtonType.bText,
            eButtonState: _continueBtnState,
            onPressed: () {
              if (updateItemProvider.updateItems!.isEmpty) {
                setState(() {
                  _continueBtnState = eButtonState.bDisable;
                });
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  _continueBtnState = eButtonState.bActive;
                });
                forwardTabPage(updateItemProvider.updateItems!);
              }
              // _tabState = eTabState.tCompleted;
            },
          );
        },
        // child:
      );


---------- 

//A TabView widget(child) is a Stateful widget

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UpdateItemProvider _updateItemProvider =
        Provider.of<UpdateItemProvider>(context, listen: false);

//inside the child widget I have a list view which loads checkbox list tiles 
and im using the provider there

ListView(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        children: _rampValues.keys.map((String key) {
                          return CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text(key, style: tBody5),
                            value: _rampValues[key],
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _rampValues[key] = value!;
                              });
                              if (_rampValues[key] == true) {
                                _updateItemProvider.addItem(new UpdateItem(
                                    title: key, selected: _rampValues[key]));
                              } else {
                                _updateItemProvider.removeWhere(key);
                              }
                            },
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),

}
```

When I execute with above updates.
I get this error

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<UpdateItemProvider> above this {child_here} Widget
This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to pass data to the parent widget?

Comment: i think you can use function callback

Comment: You can just pass the checkbox data to screen2 constructor or as an arguments while pushing to next screen. or you can use provider and store the value and check when submit button taps. As @AlunParanggiWicaksono said, you can use function callback too.

Comment: this is the reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824461/how-to-pass-data-from-child-widget-to-its-parent

Comment: im not passing the checkbox values from one screen to another. for that I could have used arguments. in here im using a tabview inside a screen and trying to get/update between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any code to go by, We can use a shopping cart as an example.

Ideally you need a way to manage your list of items and checkout in the next page.

We will use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) for this.

```
class MyCartProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
List<CartItem>? cartItems=[];
List<CartItem>? get  getCartItems=>cartItems;

removeATIndex(int i){
cartItems.removeAt(i);
notifyListeners();
}

inserAtIndex(int i,CartItem? item){
cartItems![i]=item;
notifyListeners();
}

addItem(CartItem? item){
cartItems.add(item);
notifyListeners()
}

}
```

Once we have our provider now we can insert/add data as we wish and use a consumer in the second screen to get our data.

how to add data ...

```
class MyItemsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyItemsScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyItemsScreenState createState() => _MyItemsScreenState();
}

class _MyItemsScreenState extends State<MyItemsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final cartItemsProvider = Provider.of<MyCartProvider>(context,
                    listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(children: [
//my cart items
        mycartitem(onTap:(
        cartItemsProvider.addItem(mycartItem);
        ))


      ],),
      
    );
  }
}
```

In screen B

```
Container(
            child: Consumer<MyCartProvider>(
              builder: (context,MyCartProvider cartProvider, child) {
//you can even return a list view of all the items here
                return ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed:(){ //your api calls
                    cartProvider.cartItems // the data you need is here
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks griffins. I'll have a go with this, ^_^

Comment: I've updated the question with what I've went through with yours. can you check?

Comment: glad to see you resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Your Code is Fine , the Missing Part is You need to register the provider in main.dart file .
Example :  `**Provider<UpdateItemProvider>**`  this Provider is missing. So

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]).then((_) {
    runApp(MyApp());
  });
}
/*
this is main page of this project we will use the provider system to maintian the application states 
*/

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      /**
       * Providers For the Block Module of the System
       */
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => LoginProvider()), // Add your Provider Here            
      ],
      child: Consumer<LoginProvider>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'Baghaa',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
            accentColor: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
            textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                bodyText1: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1),
                ),
                bodyText2: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1),
                ),
                headline1: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
                )),
            canvasColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 254, 229, 1),
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home:  .... Your Home widget 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks oshin. I'll try with this remark

Comment: awesome. I think I need to go through providers and state management more.. please provide me with any worthwhile references for that

Comment: Hello there, I'm sort of a student of yours. (Retrofit). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may use any kind of reactive way to access the data globally using Provider, GetX, Bloc and etc.

You may use GetX observables like below:

Reactive programming with Get is as easy as using setState.

Let's imagine that you have a name variable and want that every time you change it, all widgets that use it are automatically changed.

This is your count variable:

```
var name = 'Jonatas Borges';
```

To make it observable, you just need to add `".obs"` to the end of it:

```
var name = 'Jonatas Borges'.obs;
```

And in the UI, when you want to show that value and update the screen whenever the values changes, simply do this:

```
Obx(() => Text("${controller.name}"));
```

That's all. It's that simple.

You will find the plugin [here](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment but im not trying to pass data between screens with a navigation and arguments.

Comment: I get it, in that case, you will have to use some reactive way, I have updated the answer and implemented a simple way to solve your issue. The link for the get plugin is provided there.