# How do I pass random data between stateful widgets?

Tags: random, flutter, parameter-passing

I am having two stateful classes - FirstClass and SecondClass.
In FirstClass I have two buttons; '+' and '-', which will receive random numbers (such as 1+3 or 5-2).
Those random numbers are then to be displayed as text in SecondClass.

You can find a few examples on internet on how to pass data to a stateful widget (here are some good links).

[Passing Data to a Stateful Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818770/passing-data-to-a-stateful-widget/50818870)

[Passing data to StatefulWidget and accessing it in it's state in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287995/passing-data-to-statefulwidget-and-accessing-it-in-its-state-in-flutter)

https://medium.com/@maksimrv/reactive-app-state-in-flutter-73f829bcf6a7
[The best way to passing data between widgets in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910814/the-best-way-to-passing-data-between-widgets-in-flutter)

What all these examples have in common is that they assume that your data is final. Since my numbers are random I cannot use final- and this is where I get stuck...

I was a bit unclear in my first question, but the goal is to get an output like
2 + 5 =_  . And the user will fill in the answer in a textfield. The answer will then, after a button-press, pass back to the sum and see if the answer is correct. If answer is correct -> do this, else -> do that.

Added a nicer keyboard.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyHome());

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'passing data',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
      home: FirstClass(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstClassState createState() => _FirstClassState();
}

class _FirstClassState extends State<FirstClass> {
  final random = Random();
  int a, b, sum;
  String output;

  void changeData(String buttonName) {
    setState(() {
      a = random.nextInt(10);
      b = random.nextInt(10);

      if (buttonName == '+') {
        sum = a + b;
        output = '$a + $b = ';
      } else if (buttonName == '-') {
        if (a >= b) {
          sum = a - b;
          output = '$a - $b = ';
        } else if (b > a) {
          //sum cannot be negative here
          sum = b - a;
          output = '$b - $a = ';
        }
      }
      print(sum.toString());
      Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'));
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SecondClass(
                sum: sum,
                refresh: changeData,
                output: output,
                  )));
        });
      }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            //      Text('$a + $b = $sum'),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('+'), onPressed: () => 
changeData('+')),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('-'), onPressed: () => changeData('- 
   ')),
               ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

class SecondClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final int sum;
  final String output;
  final String correction;

  final Function refresh;

  SecondClass({this.sum, this.refresh, this.output, this.correction});

  @override
  _SecondClassState createState() => _SecondClassState();
}

class _SecondClassState extends State<SecondClass> {
  String enterAnswer;
  String correct;

  void changeAnswer() {
    if (enterAnswer.isNotEmpty) {
      if (enterAnswer == widget.sum.toString()) {
        correct = 'Correct';
        print('Correct Answer.');
      } else {
         correct = 'Wrong Answer';
         print('Wrong Answer');
      }
    } else {
      correct = 'Enter Value First';
      print('Enter Value First');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: <Widget>[
                  Text(widget.output),
                  Container(
                      width: 50.0,
                      TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          enterAnswer = val;
                         },
                      )),
                ],
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Check Answer'), onPressed: () => 
changeAnswer()),
              Text('$correct'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How come the '$correct' won't display as a text? I tried to do the same in another project and it worked, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: updated the answer, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `callback` function to get the `random` value again.

I assume you want to show the `random sum value` in second `screen()` Separate Class.

This is with `Navigator` & Class `Constructors`.

code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyHome());

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'passing data',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
      home: FirstClass(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstClassState createState() => _FirstClassState();
}

class _FirstClassState extends State<FirstClass> {
  final random = Random();
  int a, b, sum;
  String output;

  void changeData(String buttonName) {
    setState(() {
      a = random.nextInt(10);
      b = random.nextInt(10);

      if (buttonName == '+') {
        sum = a + b;
        output = '$a + $b = ';
      } else if (buttonName == '-') {
        if (a >= b) {
          sum = a - b;
          output = '$a - $b = ';
        } else if (b > a) {
          //sum cannot be negative here
          sum = b - a;
          output = '$b - $a = ';
        }
      }
      print(sum.toString());
      Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/'));
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SecondClass(
                sum: sum,
                refresh: changeData,
                output: output,
              )));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            //      Text('$a + $b = $sum'),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('+'), onPressed: () => changeData('+')),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('-'), onPressed: () => changeData('-')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final int sum;
  final String output;

  final Function refresh;

  SecondClass({this.sum, this.refresh, this.output});

  @override
  _SecondClassState createState() => _SecondClassState();
}

class _SecondClassState extends State<SecondClass> {
  String enterAnswer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Second Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(widget.output),
                  Container(
                      width: 50.0,
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          enterAnswer = val;
                        },
                      )),
                ],
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (enterAnswer.isNotEmpty) {
                    if (enterAnswer == widget.sum.toString()) {
                      print('Correct Answer.');
                    } else {
                      print('Wrong Answer');
                    }
                  } else {
                    print('Enter Value First');
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Check Answer'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am so thankful. Been working on this for weeks. For some reason my handleButtonPressed is now causing me trouble...

Comment: @J.W  - Update the answer - please check.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to second class via constructor of second class and access it by using widget.your_data. Final should be used

Because StatefulWidget inherits Widget, which is marked as @immutable, any subclass of StatefulWidget must also be immutable (i.e. all fields final).

I created simple use case by your question, see if it is what you want:

```
    class FirstClass extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      FirstClassState createState() => FirstClassState();
    }

    class FirstClassState extends State<FirstClass> {
      final random = Random();
      int a, b, sum;

      void changeData() {
        setState(() {
          a = random.nextInt(10);
          b = random.nextInt(10);
          sum = a + b;
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SecondClass(
            a: a,
            b: b,
            sum: sum,
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: changeData,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

and second class getting data is :

```
     class SecondClass extends StatefulWidget {
      final int a;
      final int b;
      final int sum;

      SecondClass({this.a, this.b, this.sum});

      @override
      _SecondClassState createState() => _SecondClassState();
    }

    class _SecondClassState extends State<SecondClass> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('${widget.a} + ${widget.b} = ${widget.sum}'),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Here if a, b and sum value is changed in first class via setState() method, all widget using those will be recreated. Thus, second class is refreshed with new data.

Comment: I do get the Integer sum to sreen 2, but I still can't get my String "output" (wich would be '$a + $b = ') to appear on the 2nd screen.